# OpenId provider/server with Java

Tags: java, web-applications, openid, provider

I'm trying to enhance an existing Java web application with an OpenId service, so that a logged in user can log into another OpenId enabled app using my web application as an OpenId provider.

My first attempt was to use [JOS](http://code.google.com/p/openid-server/) as OpenId provider which should in turn use my app's database to get existing user names and passwords. Nevertheless I could not find any documentation for JOS, when I was trying to customize JOS to make it fit to my existing app (<s>It did not even compile</s>Update: It only compiles with Java 6).

At the moment I am searching for other possible solutions, but OpenId provider frameworks seem to be scarce.

What would you recommend? Using a finished server like JOS or should I consider to enhance my application by writing my own OpenId server with libraries like openid4java?

Comment: Which is strange because writing an openId client/consumer is easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried it myself, but my team started work on a JSF+OpenId integrated application after studying these few examples:

- Client: [IBM Example:very helpful](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-openid/index.html)
- Server: [IBM Example:very helpful](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-openid2/)
- Additionally: [what is OpenId and how its work](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364125/Using-OpenID)
- Also: [openId API for Java](http://code.google.com/p/jopenid/)

That's all I know about this, I hope it helps.

Comment: My Question was how to write an OpenID *provider*, not a client. Your links are about openid clients, not about providers. Writing a client is [just one line with Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-openid-login).

Comment: As simple answer,create web-service

Answer (score 2):

In [OpenID web site](http://openid.net/), you can find [tons of options](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#plugins).

Couple of years ago, I've implemented this kind of project using [OpenID4Java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/).

(Note that in your back-end you will have to connect to some repository that keeps all users/passwords - I've used [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) for that)

HTH.